# Android Relative layout: ToLeftOf gone view

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout in which I have a `TextView` on the Left and a Spinner on the right. Also I need an error image to show if user selected incorrect variant.

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/some_text"/>
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="74dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/err"/>
        <ImageView

            android:id="@+id/err"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_error"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I want my spinner to be on the aligned to the right when error is not shown (visibility = GONE) and move it to be to the left of error image when the error is visible. How do I do that? Now it just ignores this:

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/err"
```

EDIT: thank you, I corrected the typo, but it's not the cause of the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>Perhaps you want something like this:</s>

```
<LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="74dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/err"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_error"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:** Just put your `Spinner` and `ImageView` inside a `LinearLayout` like this one.

**EDIT 2:** I just received a `+10` and as I am a bit ashamed about this solution, follow this:
So, for future questions related to this one, please ignore my answer and create your own `custom view` extending `ConstraintLayout` and include a `Spinner` and an `ImageView` on the custom layout, preferably using Kotlin. Thanks!

Comment: I don't like the idea of nested layouts, but looks like it's the best possible way, thank you

Answer (score 3):

Adding an anchor view on the right side of the relative layout can solve this issue. Add the anchor view to the RelativeLayout:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/anchor_top_right"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />
```

Replace the error ImageView relative position from `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` to `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/anchor_top_right"`. Also remove `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` from the Spinner, it's aligned to the left of the err.

Here's the full layout with the anchor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/anchor_top_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/some_text"
        />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="74dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/err"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/err"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/anchor_top_right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_error"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in your code.
It has to be `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/err"` instead of `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/err"`

Comment: The plus sign is needed only when you're defining a resource ID for the first time.

Answer (score -3):

Make 2 Spinners, and every time make one of them invisible